# How can I generate consistent random colors based on an index?

Tags: javascript

This is a javascript function to generate r g b values for the chart color in my application

```
 dynamicColors(index:number) {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
  };
```

This will random r,g,b value each time.

I have an index value as input I'm trying to generate a constant color for each index on each time.

If index is 1 ..then the r,g,b generated value should be same all the time, now its random each time.

Tried with `Math.sin()`, but didn't get expected result.

Comment: You need to store the association between index and generated color explicitly. Javascript can't do that for you.

Comment: Yes, javascript will not that, but Is there any built in function which will return same random value each time. else I need to maintain an array with these r, g,b values.

Comment: @user630209 Do you know what an enum is? How do you think that will help?

Comment: Here Enum will store the color name, so based on index i can fetch each one. correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: Off the top of my head, the simplest thing that would seem to make sense based on what you have described is generating them into a plain array.

Comment: You're not generating color names here, you're generating RGB values. Parsing an enum key is not very efficient. As @TimSeguine suggested, generating an array filled with random colors using a for-loop seems like a logical solution. That is if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: Also, you should check what [Math.sin()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine) is actually used for before trying to use it to generate random stuff.

Comment: You're not looking for randomness, you're looking for a deterministic function... one that returns same output every time same input is passed. `Math.sin` looks promising. What is the number of indexes you're expecting?

Comment: @SalmanA number of digits you mean ? or the total no of values ?

Comment: @user630209 the possible values of index parameter, like 0 to 9. You map them to PI, use the sin function to get a value between -1 and 1, then map it to 0 and 255.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: How about `hsl(${index * 100}, 100%, 85%)` ?